# Transferring an NFT via MetaMask

Tags: metamask, erc-721, send

Im onto developing my own NFT project.
Im developing with the Truffle Suite and Ganache.
I can mint the NFT to my address, but whats wondering me: I cant send the NFT because the "send" button in MetaMask is greyed out.
Is this a bug by MetaMask, is it in the nature of NFTs that you cant just send them like normal tokens or is it something completly different.

[image: Metamask screenshot]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to enable transferring Tokens via MetaMask, I want you to re-check the smart contract source code.
There might be a problem in implementing transfer function.

- Make sure 'transfer' function has been implemented correctly.
- Make sure that you haven't overridden 'beforeTokenTransfer' function for pre-process before calling transferFrom, safeTransferFrom or transfer function.
- (**Important**) Make sure you are using MetaMask mobile(Currently sending NFTs is possible only on Mobile Metamask)

Hope this tips will give you helps!

Best,

Comment: For the security reason, Metamask allows to send NFTs only via mobile wallet, not via the extension.
https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058961911-How-do-I-send-receive-or-cash-out-an-NFT-

Comment: Ok this means my code is fine and that this is "normal" behaviour in the browser extension. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

According to MetaMask support as of Jan 7, 2022:

> "Please note that while you can add NFTs as custom tokens in the
> extension, **you will not be able to see them natively in the UI**.
>
> We are actively working on improving NFT support in MetaMask
> Extension; it will be available soon, and this information will be
> updated when it becomes available. For the time being, to manage your
> NFTs via MetaMask, please use MetaMask Mobile."

https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058238591-NFT-tokens-in-your-MetaMask-wallet

Comment: I dont mean seeing the picture behind the NFT, but transferring the NFT via Metamask